# Python 3.4, Basemap 1.0.8: Problems with etopo, bluemarble, shadedrelief

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I have the following code to test `etopo()` Basemap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

m = Basemap(
           projection='merc', 
           resolution=None,
           llcrnrlon=20,
           llcrnrlat=0,
           urcrnrlon=80,
           urcrnrlat=50)
m.etopo()
plt.show()
```

There seems to be a problem with Basemaps as it keeps throwing me the error message:

---

> File "V:/Scripts/Python/Charts/test.py", line 20, in 
>       m.etopo()
>
> File
>   "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap__init__.py",
>   line 4061, in etopo
>       return self.warpimage(image='etopo',scale=scale,**kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap__init__.py",
>   line 4231, in warpimage
>       im = self.imshow(self._bm_rgba_warped,ax=ax,**kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap__init__.py",
>   line 3341, in imshow
>       ax.hold(b)
>
> NameError: name 'b' is not defined

---

No matter if I put arguments into the `etopo()` funct or not. Whatever I try I get this message. Is there anything wrong with Basemap 1.0.8 to deal with these kind of maps? Get the same error for bluemarble and shadedrelief. It does show the map, but I can't plot any data or a location marker on top of it. I think that might be related to the error?!

Anyone knows what's going on here and how to fix it? Different Basemap version?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code works fine for me with matplotlib 2.0.2, python 3.6 and basemap 1.0.8.